# Total team /mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an table like this :

```
PLAYER1_ID       #     PLAYER2_ID   #    SCORE_P1    #   SCORE_P2
1                        3                  3               5
4                        2                  5               4
2                        1                  3               4
```

What is the queries in PDO to get that ? The principle is that I don't know the number of ID... Thank you ! :

```
PLAYER ID        #    SCORE
1                      7
2                      7
3                      5
4                      5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Again there is nothing PDO specific. You can do it this way

```sql
SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
  FROM 
(
  SELECT player1_id player_id, score_p1 score
    FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT player2_id, score_p2
    FROM table_name
) q
 GROUP BY player_id
```

Output:

```
| PLAYER_ID | SCORE |
|-----------|-------|
|         1 |     7 |
|         2 |     7 |
|         3 |     5 |
|         4 |     5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3575d/2)** demo

---

**An answer to the original question:** There is nothing PDO specific in this. Just use `GROUP BY` and an aggregate `SUM()` function

```sql
SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY player_id
```

Output:

```
| PLAYER_ID | SCORE |
|-----------|-------|
|         1 |     8 |
|         3 |     6 |
|         5 |     3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cc8b/1)** demo

Comment: Thank a lot for this solution. But I edited, I was not precise...

Comment: *I was not precise* This is clearly an understatement :) See updated answer for a solution.

Comment: I have an error in phpmyadmin. #1054 - Unknown column 'player_id' in 'field list'

Comment: This means that you **incorrectly copied** the code. Take a closer look at working sqlfiddle example I provided. `player_id` is an alias that has been given to `player1_id` column in the first `SELECT` statement in `UNION ALL`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44490/discussion-between-user3149518-and-peterm)